# wpappmanifest description length

Tags: windows-phone-7

What is the maximum limit of description attribute in wmappmanifest.xml in wp7 project?

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: It seems the xml only allows around 260 characters.  Is this correct? Can this description be different from when you submit your app in the marketplace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

256 characters (including any spaces).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the limit of the Descritption attribute but actually, according to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769509%28VS.92%29.aspx), you shouldn't edit WMAppManifest.xml (except for Capability Detection):

> Important Note: The application
>   manifest file is automatically
>   generated in Visual Studio and
>   generally you should not edit the file
>   manually. Your application may become
>   unstable or unusable through file
>   modification. However, there are
>   certain circumstances where you will
>   edit the file, and these specific
>   scenarios will be called out in the
>   official MSDN documentation. One such
>   example is usage of the Windows Phone
>   Capability Detection Tool, for more
>   information see How to: Use the
>   Windows Phone Capability Detection
>   Tool. Also, some of the values in the
>   manifest file will be updated or
>   changed after you submit your
>   application to the Windows Phone
>   Marketplace.

You will be able to set the description of your app when you'll submit it on the Marketplace.

Comment: Olivier, I have an About Us page in my application where I am reading the information from the WMAppManifest file to display the Author, version, publisher, description information on the About Us page.  I guess, you will have to modify the xml file in order for your app to display this information to the user.

Comment: Do you need to read this information specifically from WMAppManifest.xml ?